# What are the Twitter Buffs for D&D Encounters, and how do they work?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-encounters

I take part in a weekly D&D Encounters program and the question often comes up. What are the "Twitter Buffs", and this is quickly followed by "how do they work"?

Comment: One warning:  While the Twitter buffs can be fun to include, they do include penalties as well as bonuses--so a player may be unhappy to find that the 'buff' is an effect that makes them have to make Acrobatics checks to move more than 4 spaces.  Likewise, some of the buffs may be encounter-breaking, such as buffs that make all enemies give combat advantage--in a party with any number of rogues, that can invalidate the challenge.  Keep this in mind before including them.  -- DM for Season 3, DnD Encounters, who used Twitter buffs for 2 chapters, then stopped.  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you follow http://twitter.com/#!/Wizards_DnD (possibly more specifically, #dndenc) on twitter, it sometimes tweets random buffs. You can then apply them to the combat rounds you are playing in. For example, last one so far has been:

> Shreds of spiderwebs catch on a breeze and flutter around your
>   heads, clinging to your faces. PCs are
>   -1 to hit lizardfolk.

Comment: My recollection is: The first one posted after a session start is the one that applies.  Encounters are supposed to last about an hour, and they are posted roughly hourly during the evening hours, so only one should ever come up. They apply immediately (or in practice when someone notices the post). They last for the duration of the session. A fair number will require GM interpretation; cramming color and rules into 140 characters is tough!

Comment: This is US centric, too (and restricted to some time zones, I guess). But since Encounters itself is US centric, I think it'll be alright.